# Are there undecidable problems for which a solution has been found?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, philosophy

I mean are there examples of problems that have been proven to be undecidable, in the sense that it would not be possible to devise a deterministic computer program that outputs a solution for an instance of the problem. And yet human mathematicians have come up with such a solution.

Comment: It depends on  what you mean with solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to find that undecidable problems often have a solution in certain special cases even though there is no general solution. The halting problem is an excellent example; certainly it is possible to prove that (most) programs written by humans intended for a practical purpose do eventually halt.

Answer (score 0):

In a certain sense made rigorous elsewhere in a mathematical logic conjecture whose origin I can't remember, every mathematician's proof is expressible in terms of basic semantics that a computer can understand given basic axioms and deduction rules. If you accept that, then no, there is no computer undecidable problem that a mathematician can figure out a deterministic decision procedure for.

Comment: But there are meta proofs, like Godel's proof of his incompleteness theorem. He proved that a certain statement was true even though it was undecidable. That was what made it so disturbing. It'd probably be easier to live with undecidable statements if they couldn't be true or false.

Comment: There is nothing disturbing about it at all. It just shows the limits of formal systems. In particular look at (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_second_problem#Modern_viewpoints_on_the_status_of_the_problem)